# Symfony: cache a POST method

Tags: post, caching, symfony1

I've read the tutorials for Symfony and it says that POST requests are never cached. Can I override this so that I can cache the resulted page for the POST request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hopefuly you know that in most cases caching a POST requests is not what you want ;)

Below some tips.

**Cache filter**

Cache filter is responsible for caching the response. By default symfony uses *sfCacheFilter* class and you can change it in *filters.yml* file of your application.

**View cache manager**

*sfCacheFilter* doesn't do much. It uses the view cache manager to do all the work.

Default implementation (*sfViewCacheManager* class) has a *isCacheble()* method. You could start here as it returns false for everything which is not a GET request.

View cache manager class can be changed in factories.yml file. You could write your own class by extending the *sfViewCacheManger* and overloading some of its behavior.

Answer (score 3):

kuba's answer is technically correct, but are you *sure* you want to be caching a POST? If possible, it is preferable to redirect the user, storing some values on the user.

Comment: Agreed. You should try changing the POST into a GET rather than hacking the framework.